# Django-nonrel import cache fail

Tags: django-nonrel

I am trying to setup django-nonrel on GAE (Google App Engine) - 
following the steps here http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation

The test application works great -

I was able to use the cache API in the application, but not so for the tests and shell:

Attempting to `from django.core.cache import cache` in the shell gives me:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "django-testapp/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 182, in <module>
    cache = get_cache(DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS)
  File "django-testapp/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 180, in get_cache
    return backend_cls(location, params)
  File "django-testapp/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 154, in __init__
    import memcache
ImportError: No module named memcache
```

Similarly attempting  `./manage.py test` fails the same way.

Any idea why `./manage runserver` works fine, but `./manage shell` or `./manage test` fails to import cache?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to Google App Engine 1.6.0 from 1.5.5 .

I solved the problem by installing `python-memcached`:

```
pip install python-memcached
```

Comment: I had this problem trying to runserver on OSX and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For gentoo users it's recommended:
`emerge -av dev-python/python-memcached`

Answer (score 0):

I alse do like this:

```
sudo pip install python-memcached
```

then restart the django, it works.